# Law of Demeter and return values

Tags: language-agnostic, coupling, law-of-demeter

According to the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), can you call methods on returned objects?

E.g.

```
<?php
class O
{
    public function m($http)
    {
        $response = $http->get('http://www.google.com');
        return $response->getBody(); // violation?
    }
}
?>
```

$http->get() returns an object. Does this count as an object created/instantiated within M? If you can not call methods on it (according to LoD), how would you handle this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a violation of the Law of Demeter, [given](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> More formally, the Law of Demeter for
>   functions requires that a method M of
>   an object O may only invoke the
>   methods of the following kinds of
>   objects:
>
> - O itself
> - M's parameters
> - any objects created/instantiated within M
> - O's direct component objects
> - a global variable, accessible by O, in the scope of M

Since $response is an object that is created within M, you can invoke a method upon that object without violation.  However, it would be a violation to access properties beyond `getBody()`:

```
$length = $response->getBody()->length;
```

Sometimes you can say that the law can be simplified by saying it's the "one dot" rule, meaning that you can access one property or method deep.

Comment: Except that the dot operator in PHP is for concatenating strings. :-) Slight brainfart in that last `.length` bit, I think.

Comment: does a call (like a getter)

Answer (score 6):

On the one hand, `$response` appears to have been created within method `m`, so the answer would appear to be yes.

On the other hand, since `$http` has been passed in to `m`, the object returned by `$http->get()` that is now represented by `$response` might be a member of `$http` that might have been created prior to entry to `m`.

Considering the "only one dot" (or, in this case arrow) interpretation of the Law, rewriting the body of your function as `return $http->get('http://www.google.com')->getBody();` suggests that it might be a violation.  Saving the intermediate members as local variables seems like a dodgy way to avoid the one-dot principle.

I can't give a definitive answer.  To some extent, I think it depends on how much you trust the `$http->get()` to give you a newly created object rather than a pre-existing member.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to solve this is to create the object within m(), and let http->get() fill it with information.

```
class O
{
    public function m($http)
    {
        $response = new HttpResponse();
        $http->get('http://www.google.com', & $response);
        return $response->getBody(); // no violation, since we made $response ourselves.
    }
}
```